# How to solve docker-compose docker mysql ECONNREFUSED?

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker compose:

```
services:
  server:
    container_name: server
    build: 
      context: ./BE
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.prod
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST_IP: mysql
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    links:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysqldb
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE # CAP_SYS_NICE
    # container_name: my_very_special_server
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - ./DbScripts/DumpTodoOnly.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/DumpTodoOnly.sql
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: todo
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password!
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password!
    healthcheck:
      test: "mysql -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD content -e 'select 1'"
      interval: 1s
      retries: 120
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: dev_pma
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3307
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8183:80
  client:
    container_name: FE
    build: 
      context: ./FE
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    tty: true
volumes:
  db_data:
```

When i run: `docker-compose up -d --build`

Everything builds without errors.

I viste my php admin: http://localhost:8183/index.php?route=/&route=%2F

And I can see that my two tables are created:

[image]

Problem:

On the server I have a route http://localhost:4000/api/create

Which basically take in a body param that should add a todo to the todos table.

but when using postman I get :

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": {
        "errno": "ECONNREFUSED",
        "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
        "syscall": "connect",
        "address": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 3306,
        "fatal": true
    }
}
```

I thought that ny db image did not get build in time so I added a healtcheck in the compose file:

```
healthcheck:
  test: "mysql -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD content -e 'select 1'"
  interval: 1s
  retries: 120
```

and on the server image:

```
depends_on:
        mysql:
          condition: service_healthy
```

But when I wanted to build the compose file I got:

**ERROR: for server  Container "a7916ff588af" is unhealthy.
Encountered errors while bringing up the project**

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like your `server` is trying to connect to MySQL on `localhost` / `127.0.0.1` where it should be using the `MYSQL_HOST_IP` environment variable, aka `mysql`

Comment: Your healthcheck probably fails because you don't have a `content` database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while to update this question.

@Phil was correct. I needed to add the image name on my sql configuration in node express rather than the ip.